# Image outside of div in infobubble

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobubble

I am working on Google Map and showing an InfoWindow using the [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/) library. My problem is that when I show image for outside div with CSS properties it's showing half image that is within div.

Here is my CSS code:

```
#wider-header{
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
}

#wide-header img {
    position:relative;
    top:-70px;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    border: 2px solid #d81f27;  
}
```

and the JavaScript:

```
infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
    map: map,
    content: "<div id='wide-header'><img id='jdImg' src='http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02474/cat-eyebrows-1_2474686k.jpg' width='100' height='100' alt='userImage'></div>",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151),
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 4,
    arrowSize: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
    disableAutoPan: false,
    hideCloseButton: true,
    arrowPosition: 50,
    arrowStyle: 3
});
infoBubble2.open();
```

The code above results in this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `top:-70px;` in the CSS for the image? That looks like what's moving the `img` outside of its containig `div`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro- for moving img outside of div in top direction

Comment: So you want it to be in top, but visible outside the div?

Comment: yes, my requirement is to show half image within and half outside of div.

Comment: Does removing the `overflow: hidden;` from #wider-header show the image? If not, it may be the bubble style the one that has an `overflow:hidden` and it will be trickier

Comment: i tried to remove overflow: hidden; from #wider-header but problem remained same. one more thing if change parent div attribute from overflow:auto to overflow:visible by manually inspect element it showing the same result which is require.

Answer (score 1):

i found my solution by changed these lines in infobubble.js library

```
     // Content area
             var contentContainer = this.contentContainer_ = document.createElement('DIV');
             contentContainer.style['overflowX'] = 'auto';
             contentContainer.style['overflowY'] = 'auto';
into
             // Content area
             var contentContainer = this.contentContainer_ = document.createElement('DIV');
             contentContainer.style['overflowX'] = 'visible';
             contentContainer.style['overflowY'] = 'visible';
```

[Here is the required solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA5XY.png)

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Maybe you could extend/suggest an extension to the infobubble.js library so it is more general and it has an option that enables/disables overflow